# php mailer Getting SMTP connect() failed Error suddenly, rest working properly

Tags: php, error-handling, phpmailer

I am using php mailer for making a confirmation mail after signing up. Every time after reloading the page and submitting the signup form I get the `SMTP connect() failed` error for first time and then it starts working correctly. If I reload again same issue occur again.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code you are using. You've described the problem, but without the code it is unlikely that anyone can provide you the correct solution unless they happen to guess what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you get specific error or display what's wrong in the code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer; /*Other prameters*/

if(!$mail->send()) { 
    echo 'Message could not be sent.'; echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; exit; 
}
```